# On Editor Action Listener doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, view, textview, keyboard

I need to override the work of the keyboard (Android), I write some code.
At the onCreate method I write:

```
editNumber = findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
editNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
editPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
editPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
editPassword.setOnTouchListener(
    View.OnTouchListener { view, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                if (event.rawX >=
                        editPassword.right - resources.getDimension(R.dimen._48pxh)) {
                    editPassword.setTransformationMethod (
                        if (passwordVisible) null
                        else PasswordTransformationMethod());
                    passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                    editPassword.setSelection(password.size);
                }
                else {
                    editPassword.requestFocus();
                    super.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            }
        }
    false;
});
```

I only init my view elements and add listeners.
And override the method:

```
    override fun onEditorAction(view: TextView?, code: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d("My", "Sddfsd") //This log never write
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.editNumber -> {
                //I think its not matter what i do here for this question
                return true;
            }
            R.id.password -> {
                //I think its not matter what i do here for this question
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Logs show that the method onEditorAction never works. I try to use onKeyListner, but it doesn't work too, but its works with a physical keyboard from a PC. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I try it, It isnt work